# Trello multiple due dates

Tags: trello

Can I assign multiple due dates to a particular card for the different lists (phases)  that the project needs to be at. Eg the expected start date and the expected completion date for a card needs to be assigned even though the task may not have started

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. A card can only have *one* due date.

A workaround may be to *create several cards* that stand for the individual phases of your project. This would also allow the different phases / expected start and completion dates to show up in calendar view.